# S3 Trigger Lambda based on Priority

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I am trying to design a system, a end user will upload file to S3 of High or Lo priority. I want to invoke Lambda (with or without SQS) - such that the High priority files get processed first.

Can I use [Configuring event notifications using object key name filtering](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/notification-how-to-filtering.html) with some object prefix  /hi /lo to send to hi or lo priority SQS queue. I could use SQS Lambda Trigger invoke suitable Lambda function.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming

Answer (score 1):

You can separate the processing as you described, but there is no priority or weighting for lambda event sources, so it won't really help you in terms of making sure the high priority get's processed first.

Lambda functions scale out though, so you could have by default up to 1000 parallel execution contexts that perform work. Depending on your workload high/low priority queues may not be necessary.
If you want to artificially slow down processing on the low priority queue, you can duplicate the Lambda function, assign one queue as an event source to each and limit the number of parallel execution contexts ([*Reserved Concurrency*](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-concurrency.html)) on the low priority Lambda.

Comment: good point, my lambda just needs to push the task to some worker (cluster) - it would be long running task. Not sure, but I could have a Hi and Lo priority cluster. Not sure how/what.

Comment: Can the cluster not just directly read from the high and low priority queues while working on the high priority queue first?

Comment: Yeah I think not using lambda is a better/suitable option - just have the Hi/Lo Qs and the cluster can pickup based on priority. My Lambda actually would do nothing _just get tempted to us Lambda_.  My additional design issue is - I need to process the 'batch' after all files are uploaded, I can start copying files into the cluster as they arrive/notified. Is there a good design paradigm for last file upload - just use some file naming convention?

Comment: A file naming convention would probably also be my approach for this, I can't think of any better solution of the top of my head.